# Android ant build: How to configure library order?

Tags: android, ant, build

I am building an android application using one external somelibrary.jar file. In eclipse I can build it by

1. Configuring build path
2. Adding external somelibrary.jar
3. Change library order so that somelibrary.jar is before android system libraries.

Now I would like to build this project with ant. I dropped this somelibrary.jar file to /libs folder, but build does not work. I guess that this because somelibrary.jar has to be before android system libraries.

How can I change library order in ant build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to solve how to put this library before android.jar in the build order. However I was able to do workaround: Merge this library into the android.jar with these steps:

1. Unzip android.jar to "unzipped_android_jar" folder
2. Unzip somelibrary.jar on top of this "unzipped_android_jar" folder
3. Repackage android.jar by zipping the folder
4. Rename zip file to android.jar

Your library is now merged into system library android.jar. You can use this by replacing android.jar at SDK_FOLDER/platforms/android-N/android.jar

Answer (score 0):

Order is not important. What is happening is that somelibrary.jar is not seen by ANT

Comment: In my build it does. It is a custom library that adds something on top of android system packages. If it is not before android system jar's in the build, it will not compile on eclipse. I know this is weird library but I cannot change it I fear.